# Equivalent of assigning char on c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, equivalent

Does anyone know how to implement the following c++ code in c#

c++

```
char t = '\0';
t += (char)3;
```

the output of t would be equal to '\x3'

if I implement the same code in c#

```
char t = '\0';
t += (char)3;
```

the output would be different t = '\u0003'

How could I get the same result in c#??
thanks

Comment: Did you mean to write `char` instead of `chat`?

Comment: yes I meant char

Comment: The code you posted has no output. Maybe you mean the value of `t`.  In .NET a `char` and a `string` are inherently Unicode.  That's why you see `\u0003`: because that's how a Unicode character is represented.  The thing is, it's still the same value.  3 is 3 is 3.  C++ and C# are different languages so don't expect them to behave the same way.

Answer (score 3):

In both languages the escape sequence `\xnn` represents a character with the specified byte value `nn` in hexadecimal.

In both languages the escape sequence `\unnnn` represents the unicode code point `nnnn`.

It so happens that the byte value 3 corresponds to the unicode code point U+0003 in the encoding used by C#. This is why the output in C# is `\u0003`.

The code in both languages does roughly the same thing and both `t`s will store a value of `3` after both code run. The difference is in the format of the output. I don't know how you get `\u0003` as output in C#. `Console.WriteLine` will print the character out, not its unicode code point.

You can't really get the same output in C# because C# `char`s are represented differently than those in C++. C++ `char`s are usually 1 byte, while C# `char`s are as big as a `ushort`.

Comment: A tiny nitpick: size of char is always 1 byte in both c and c++, not just usually